# Getting error in store register data into mongodb data base

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to create a register page then store username and password to UserDB database but I get this error. After I input email and password and hit register, the browser keep loading. I see this error in hyper. When I check database by using show dbs in cmd i didn't see userDB.
[image]

here is my code

`````
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27107/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const userSchema = {
    email: String,
    password: String
};

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


app.get ("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get ("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("login");
});

app.get ("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("register");
});


app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save(function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("secrets");
        }
    });
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Connect to port 3000");
}); ````
`````

Comment: Its probably the database server is not started.

Comment: I tried restart my database, it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the database started, up and running? Are you able to connect from a tool like `mongo` shell or Compass?

Comment: yes it is, I was able to use mongo to check my database and found that UserDB wasn't created.

Comment: In case the database and collection do not exist, when you insert the first document both will get created.

Comment: yeah, so I think the problem is I can not insert data or save it

Comment: Even from mongo shell? Does the database access has some security enabled?

Comment: I solve the problem, I make typo mistake I typed "27107" instead of "27017" that why It can not connect to database.